# How to configure seperate accounts for EF data access/mutations and migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, security, entity-framework-migrations, account

For security reasons, we would like to have 2 sets of credentials; 1 for the migrations to use and be allowed to do structural changes to the database and 1 for data access/mutations. Anyone done something like that before? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Update-Database to apply migrations, there is the ConnectionString argument in this command. You should be able to use it when migrating the DB. And the data access credentials could be stored in the config file for "normal" usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good tip, but we would like to allow the application to do the migrations itself using a second set of credentials.

Comment: If the application is a desktop one, then the user could provide the credentials before the update is started. Then the connection string can be built (could be even based on the connection string in the config file) and passed to the migrator object before the Update function is called. It also could be that the user's account is used to connect to the DB (trusted connection) and this one user, when logged into the domain, would be able to run the update.

Comment: If it is a web application, hm... Maybe have two connection strings in the config file. Set the credentials in the "update" one only before updating the application and use this connection string for update. Or, if it is ok that a user would have to run the migration, use the Migrate.exe application, providing the connection string as a parameter. This one would not be fully automatic but more secure than the first option... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj618307.aspx)